# How can I receive a real time notification from a Oracle table when a value change occurs?

Tags: sql, oracle, event-listener

**Part 1**: I would like to receive real-time notification when value changes from A -> B in an Oracle table that is an on-prem vendor database.

*Part 2: Upon receiving the event a process flow will kick-off to take appropriate action such as executing WebAPI calls, Emails and SMSs.*

**What would be a good solution architecture for Part 1?**

- Since it's a vendor database writing and executing custom triggers on their tables is not desirable.
- Plan B is to write a JOB to poll the tables on a schedule and pick up the changes.

Comment: Apparently, plan B it is, as you can't do anything in the database itself.